# What product will insulate an exterior PVC pipe coming out of the ground with a faucet on it?

Tags: plumbing, insulation, pipe, freezing

We want to insulate from freezing an exterior 24" tall PVC pipe coming out of the ground that has a faucet on it ~ a heated product is not plausible in our situation.  Are there other products that will successfully insulate the pipe against freezing?  We live in the western side of Oregon, where the winters are generally mild, but occasionally/rarely reach 10-20 degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a "frost-proof hydrant" (which will have a garden hose thread, not a fire hose thread.)

That is a valve that is buried below frost line. On the hose side of the valve, there is a small, deliberate leak (this should not leak when the valve is open.) When the valve is closed, the leak drains water from the standing part of the pipe.

Without heat, even a fairly absurd amount of insulation will not prevent a pipe standing in the cold with non-moving water from freezing; so this type of valve removes the standing water.

Here is a picture, from the state of Indiana (they evidently don't want this type to be used due to the subsurface drain.):

[image: frost-free hydrant]

Here  (from Simmons, a manufacturer - no affiliation or recommendation implied) is the more complex "sanitary" alternative type with a sealed canister and a Venturi to drain it when water is next used:
[image: sanitary frost-free hydrant]

Comment: In the diagram the valve is underground.  Does this valve automatically shut off or does it need to be manually shut off"

Comment: @RET The valve is manualy shut off from above ground via the control rod down the middle of the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting problem. I'm wondering if you can bury your water supply line so that it would be unaffected by the frozen ground temperature? (Think below perma-frost and ground heave). Also, if the water is being piped a short distance from building that is already being heated maybe an auto draining valve (as @Ecnerwal mentioned) could be installed to drain standing water and prevent freezing. If the water doesn't need to be potable you could modify the plumbing so as to have some sort of alcohol or glycerin tank mix with the out going aqua (water). Or have it plumbed for a continuous loop (circulation) with the interior piping run so as to be heated by a house furnace. This way there is no standing water it's always circulating and heated (or warmed) by a heat source already in use. I would insulate all pipes with as much pipe insulation as possible.

Comment: We purchased and used a yard hydrant (similar to diagram above).